# DART: attribute of attribute of class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a classmodel in dart with a json mapper like

```
class DA_Field {   
  final String strGROUP;

  DA_Field({
    required this.strGROUP, });

  static DA_Field fromJson(json) => DA_Field(
    strGROUP: json['GROUP'] as String,   ); 
}
```

and I want to set a attribute of the attribute strGROUP via a function - so that I can call that sub-attribute 'width' for example by:

```
intWidth = DA_Field.strGROUP.width
```

My first attempt was to create a setter - but after a lot of google, I only get in touch to create a setter for the whole modelclass, not for all of the single attributes.

The values should be calculated by a function outside of the class - I thought maybe this could be possible by .forEach function - like ?

```
DA_Field.forEach((k,v) => k.width = functionxx(k));
```

But i get following errors:

```
error: The setter 'width' isn't defined for the type 'DA_Field'. (undefined_setter...)
error: The argument type 'void Function(DA_Field, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(DA_Field)'. (argument_type_not_assignable)
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to do that?

Thanks..

Comment: but you define `strGROUP` as a `String`, there is nothing called `width` in `String`

Comment: uh, ahh, I now understand.. The class takes the attribute of String.... how stupid from me :-(